# Smart activation (input element)

Tags: javascript, html, input

There is a table, the number of cells can be different.
In my work, I have a task to implement the following:

1. By double-clicking on the input, it should become editable, if the user moved the focus from it, again - it cannot be edited.
2. Same as point 1, but only for a single tap on a mobile device.

Here's my code, but that's only 33% of the task. Even if you don't write the code, tell me what functions to implement it with. Thank you :)

```html
<table>
    <td><input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly=false;" value="text"></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly=false;" value="text"></td>
    <td><input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly=false;" value="text"></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly=false;" value="text"></td>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please specify why would you want to do this? It seems to be doing literally nothing. Unless the task is actually to render the label only and on click/double click replace it with the input field. If not, then making it read only when not focused makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest do it on one click, not double i think is more intuitive.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
   const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input.editable");
   for(let input of inputs){
      input.addEventListener("dblclick", (e) =>{
         e.target.removeAttribute("readonly");
      })
      input.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
         e.target.removeAttribute("readonly");
      })
      
      input.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
        e.target.setAttribute("readonly", "true")
      })
   }
})
```

```css
input.editable:read-only{
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td>
    <input class="editable" type="text" readonly>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="editable" type="text" readonly>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="editable" type="text" readonly>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="editable" type="text" readonly>
  </td>
</table>
```